# R Selenium - Form Submit Button Click

Tags: java, r, forms, selenium, submit

Basically we have this

```
<form action="https://audiomax.adswizz.com/api/v2/audiomax/reports/generate?type=SALES_TYPE_ID_HERE&amp;from=NUMBERS_HERE&amp;to=MORENUMBERS_HERE&amp;format=XLSX&amp;sessionID=AUTOGENERATESESSIONIDHERE" method="POST" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <input type="hidden" name="breakdowns" ng-value="ssp_form.report_type.value" value="SALES_CHANNEL_DEAL">
                <!-- ngIf: ssp_form.selected_entity.id && ssp_form.selected_entity.id !== 'all' -->
                <input type="hidden" name="format" ng-value="ssp_form.format" value="XLSX">
                <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn btn-md download xh-highlight">GENERATE REPORT</button>
            </form>
```

and I can use something like

```
report <- login$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//BUTTON[@type='submit'][text()='GENERATE REPORT']")
```

it finds the element properly, but when I attempt this I get:

```
report$clickElement()
```

> Selenium message:Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has
>   changed since it was looked up For documentation on this error, please
>   visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30
>   17:37:03' System info: host: '92ab6929688e', ip: '172.17.0.2',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-93-generic',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>
> Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
>            Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
>            class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
>            Further Details: run errorDetails method

I've tried pretty much everything, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find xptha by text and its working for me..Try this

```
report <- login$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//button[contains(text(),'GENERATE REPORT')]")
```

Comment: still, you are getting this issue?

Comment: I get the response: Selenium message:The given selector //[text()='GENERATE REPORT'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[text()='GENERATE REPORT'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: report <- login$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[text()='GENERATE REPORT']") Try this

Comment: So using that it finds the element, but when I do `report$clickElement()` it gives me this error again: Selenium message:Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: try this report <- login$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//button[contains(text(),'GENERATE REPORT')]")
  I hope it will work..Using this xpath we will get button with button text so that it will be clickable

Comment: Nope, same error: Selenium message:Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up. 
Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
         Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.